# Error with my boolean if statement (Django)

Tags: python, django, if-statement, boolean

I am building a table like the following:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>List of car parts available:</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Price</th>
    </tr>
    {% for product in products_list %}
    <tr>
      <td>{{ product.name }}</td>
      <td>${{ product.price }}</td>
      <td>{% if product.in_cart == False: %}
              <a href="products/cart/">Add to cart</a>
          {% else %}
              {{ print('')}}
      </td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
  </table>
```

I would like to say if the product's value for in_cart is False (meaning it is not in cart), then add a link to the cart url.

However I get this error: Could not parse the remainder: ':' from 'False:'

Then, how can I change its value to true?

This is my views:

```
def index(request):
    products_list = Product.objects.all()
    template = loader.get_template('products/index.html')
    context = {'products_list': products_list}
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))

def cart(request):
    cart_list = Product.objects.filter(in_cart = True)
    template_cart = loader.get_template('cart/cart.html')
    context = {'cart_list': cart_list}
    return HttpResponse(template_cart.render(context, request))
```

Thanks!

Comment: You shouldn't need the `:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't add colon `:` to your `if` statement. [Here's example how to use Django if in templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#firstof).

Also `{% if not product.in_cart %}` will look way better ;)

Comment: Thanks!! I would also like to change the value of product.in_cart according to which link the user clicks, how can I do that?

Comment: @NicoBar You must make a request to your backend using e.g [**AJAX**](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp) or normal **GET** or **POST**.

Answer (score 0):

The Django template does not allow this syntax `if product.in_cart == False:` ended with a colon `:` like Python does, neither `()` parentheses will not work

Try the following:

```
{% if not product.in_cart %} 
    <a href="products/cart/">Add to cart</a>
{% else %}
    {{ print('')}}{{ print }}
{% endif %}
```

Don't forget to end the `if` statement with `endif`

The [Django Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#if) will be helpful, take a look!!!

Comment: Thank you so much it worked!! Now how can I change the value of product.in_cart to true or false according to which link the user clicks?

Comment: @NicoBar You can handle this by using AJAX. Use jQuery to make things easier.